# Scaling Images for different devices

Tags: android, imageview, image-scaling

I wanted to make a 3x3 grid of ImageViews. To do so, I created a TableLayout with 3 TableRows and put 3 ImageViews in each TableRow. To make the imageViews the same width, I set their `android:layout_width=0dp` and made their `android:layout_weight` equal.To scale the height, I did it programmatically -

```
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    Configuration configuration = getResources().getConfiguration();
    int screenWidthDp = configuration.screenWidthDp;
    int imageSize = screenWidthDp / 3;

    TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) tableRow.getChildAt(j);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = imageSize;
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine on an mdpi device -

[image: Correct Output]

But not at all for an xxhdpi device -

[image: Incorrect Ouput]

As the dpi of the image is being obtained dynamically, I'm unsure as to what should be the exact dimensions of the images in my drawable-xxhdpi, drawable-hdpi folders. What would be the most efficient manner to solve this problem?

**EDIT** - I know that I need to make different versions of the image for different devices. My question is how do I find out what resolution to scale an image to using a photo-editing software like GIMP, etc.

Comment: have different images for type of devices

Comment: You can check out the give sites in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ration of Android drawable folder Images Should be like this:

36x36 (0.75x) for low-density
48x48 (1.0x baseline) for medium-density
72x72 (1.5x) for high-density
96x96 (2.0x) for extra-high-density
180x180 (3.0x) for extra-extra-high-density
192x192 (4.0x) for extra-extra-extra-high-density

For more information refer this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use TiCons for this.

http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/

or Andorid asset studio for this

http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Answer (score 0):

You can set your ImageView width and height by multiplying device screen density based on the image from your mdpi folder.

Here's way to get density.

`DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();     getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int density = metrics.density;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need not to bother about the resolutions, There are few sites with the tools that creates all icons or all expected resolution and also create separate folders as required in Android.
You can use them to get all sized icons

### Check out the followings:

1. [Android assets Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html)
2. [Android Icon Generator](http://www.androidicongenerator.net/)
3. [Icon Styler](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/#.VKOfbXsmQvU)
4. [Make App Icon](http://makeappicon.com/#)